# Need help: Getting error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis, can't find solution

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't understand what I am missing. Using Oracle Apex for SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE Employees
(
    EmployeeID CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    LastName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Title VARCHAR(30),
    TitleOfCourtesy VARCHAR(25),
    BirthDate DATE(7),
    HireDate DATE(7),
    Address VARCHAR(60),
    City VARCHAR(15),
    Region VARCHAR(15),
    PostalCode VARCHAR(10),
    Country VARCHAR(15),
    HomePhone VARCHAR(24),
    Extension VARCHAR(4),
    Notes VARCHAR(600),
    ReportsTo NUMBER(22),
    PhotoPath VARCHAR(255),
    SIN CHAR(9),
    CONSTRAINT Employees_EmployeeID_pk PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID)
)
```

Comment: There is no precision for date type.  remove (7)  . Didn't you ask the same question yesterday?

Comment: You shouldn't be using `char(..)` - use `varchar2` instead. `char()` has absolutely not advantages but some very annoying disadvantages.

Comment: Isn't `SIN` is a function and cannot be a column name without escaping its name?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to debug this kind of errors is remove row by row until you no longer get the error. Then figure out why that row returns an error. In this case the error happens for column birthdate. Reason is that `DATE(7)` is not a valid datatype in oracle. You cannot specify precision for DATE. Remove the (7) and it will work like a charm.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
  employeeid       CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  lastname         VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  firstname        VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  title            VARCHAR(30),
  titleofcourtesy  VARCHAR(25),
  birthdate        DATE,
  hiredate         DATE,
  address          VARCHAR(60),
  city             VARCHAR(15),
  region           VARCHAR(15),
  postalcode       VARCHAR(10),
  country          VARCHAR(15),
  homephone        VARCHAR(24),
  extension        VARCHAR(4),
  notes            VARCHAR(600),
  reportsto        NUMBER(22),
  photopath        VARCHAR(255),
  sin              CHAR(9),
  CONSTRAINT employees_employeeid_pk PRIMARY KEY ( employeeid )
)
```

As usual, very well [documented](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950)